# How to know when MySQL is reaching memory limits of server?

Tags: mysql, performance, monitoring, memory-management, cpu-usage

How do I know the memory consumption of MySQL, and when it is reaching the memory limits of my server? I would like to know to so I can diagnose performance problems when they arise.

Comment: that's perhaps not the ideal way to go about identifying performance problems.  Do you have particular queries that are slow?

Comment: On what platform are you running MySQL (Windows, Ubuntu, OS X)? The mechanism for inspecting memory usage varies by operating system.

Comment: Is http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor-features.html something on the lines of what you are looking for? This is usually the kind of tool used by DBA's to monitor databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to check amount of memory consumed by application is to use 'top' command on Unix and 'Performance monitor' on Windows